# Why am I not getting 10 rep for an upvote?

Tags: support

Recently I answered [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852145/javascript-to-copy-text-from-textbox-to-div/21852182#21852182) question on Stack Overflow. Instead of getting 10 reputation, it got 3. I didn't get any downvotes on that answer. I am bit confused at this stage. Can anybody explain what is going?

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the reputation cap. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work for details.